# Changing count header in API but it's not changing response limit

Tags: json, api, api-key, insomnia

`curl "https://1xbet158657.top/LineFeed/Get1x2_VZip?sports=1&count=50&lng=en&tf=478&tz=3&mode=4&country=190&partner=7&getEmpty=true" ^ -H "authority: 1xbet158657.top" ^ -H "accept: */*" ^ -H "accept-language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7,ru;q=0.6" ^ -H "cookie: v3fr=1; fast_coupon=true; lng=en; flaglng=en; typeBetNames=full; che_g=0d2adb26-876b-9b59-cd6c-bafacf8d3e8a; pushfree_status=canceled; sh.session=40a333e7-c2b5-4c0d-866b-82496f9fd6a8; SESSION=5bd2611d7e6c8020bf1e9df27ad34ce7; visit=1-2d8c701f06e83621280502f06401f183; auid=sv0kXWRvSBA+gkfLAwk/Ag==; tzo=3; completed_user_settings=true; btc-showed=1; disable_live_express=1; disable_line_express=1; compact_vid_off=1; che_i=19; dnb=1; _glhf=1685034400; ggru=195; right_side=right" ^ -H "referer: https://1xbet158657.top/en/line" ^ -H "sec-ch-ua: ^\^"Google Chrome^\^";v=^\^"113^\^", ^\^"Chromium^\^";v=^\^"113^\^", ^\^"Not-A.Brand^\^";v=^\^"24^\^"" ^ -H "sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0" ^ -H "sec-ch-ua-platform: ^\^"Windows^\^"" ^ -H "sec-fetch-dest: empty" ^ -H "sec-fetch-mode: cors" ^ -H "sec-fetch-site: same-origin" ^ -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/113.0.0.0 Safari/537.36" ^ -H "x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest" ^ --compressed`

When i paste it into insomnia, and edit count header to 500, response is not changing, again it's loading 50 values. How I can solve it?
Thank you.

Comment: If I were you I wouldn't hand out any session id's. Best to invalidate those sessions ASAP

Comment: @DarkBee you mean delete my Chrome history and restart my modem to change IP?

Comment: If the site where the session id belongs to has a feature "log out from all devices" I would click it. By passing/leaking your session id people are able to access your account on the said website

Comment: ah thanks for your warning and response @DarkBee .I was not logged into my account on this website to view that response. So you think it's not possible view whole response without count limit? Bcuz it had to allow me to see 180 response when I change "count" paramenter to 500 but again it loaded 50 values. It means that server has default 50 values limit?